Will users still be able to log in if I change host?
The title says it all.
I am taking over a website from somebody who lives in another country and will host it in the UK.
Once the migration process is complete (moving it from their host to mine), should users still be able to log in as normal?
I am aware of several tools that can assist with migration, making a smooth process.  (The most commonly-referenced one in my experience is All-in-One WP Migration, and that is the tool I have chosen to use.)
I have also read that pointing the domain to the new host is part of the process, which of course makes sense.
However, I have not migrated a user-focused site before so have nothing to base anything on.
Any assistance would be great.
Thank you in advance.

Changing host won't do anything to change the login process or the users' credentials. Provided everything's set up correctly at the new host the move should be entirely transparent to the users.
